# Compare date in database table with current time

Tags: php, sql

I'm having a challenge comparing the current date with a date set in a database table `CF_PROCUREMENT` with the column name `TENDER_DEADLINE_PROC` for verification code in a portal. The `TENDER_DEADLINE_PROC` field needs to be in comparison with the current time but what seems to be put into comparison is two current timestamps. I am new to PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM CF_PROCUREMENT WHERE CASEFOLDERID = '$code'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($db,$sql); 

if ($result) {  
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
    if($rows==true){
        $date = new DateTime($row['TENDER_DEADLINE_PROC']);
        $date = $date ->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        $now = new DateTime();
        $now = $now ->format('d/m/Y');
        if($date > $now){
            $mail->Subject = 'PORTAL Deadline Alert';  
            $mail ->Body =  ' 
            <html> 
            <body> 
                <h1>Deadline has lapsed</h1> 
               
            </body> 
            </html>';
            $mail->send();
        }else{
            $mail->Subject = 'PORTAL Email Verification';  
            $mail ->Body =  ' 
            <html> 
            <body> 
                <h1>VERIFICATION CODE</h1> 
                <h2>Code: <b>'.$otp_code.'</b>
            </body> 
            </html>';
}
```

Comment: You could let database compare the time for you. `select case when TENDER_DEADLINE_PROC <= getdate() then 'PORTAL Deadline Alert' else 'PORTAL Email Verification' end as subject, other, columns from`... as is `$date` and `$now` are strings so `>` won't work

Comment: You could potentially use MySQL's `NOW()` function to add a where condition to your SQL query like so (and cut out the need for the comparison in PHP): `$sql = "SELECT * FROM CF_PROCUREMENT WHERE CASEFOLDERID = '$code' AND TENDER_DEADLINE_PROC > NOW()";` This is dependant on the 'TENDER_DEADLINE_PROC' being a date/datetime field however